# Is it possible to use xdotool to enter a web console command?

Tags: linux, shell, xdotool, web-console

Is it possible to use xdotool to enter a web console command like this command:

```
$("#var2").css("move", - 44 + "deg")
```

Comment: I would think no because xdotool only does what you can do with keyboard and mouse... it doesn't communicate directly with the browser... Maybe one work-around is to have it enter the Javascript into a hidden text field and use the evil eval() to execute it...!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you *really* trying to achieve here? It might be better to figure out a better way to approach the problem that your question attempts to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Yes is possible, you can use web console or address bar.
with this step:

- Focus on Browser
- press F12
- Type code

this example xdotool script using web console:

```
search --sync --onlyvisible --name "chrome"
windowactivate --sync
keydown F12
sleep 1
type --clearmodifiers --delay 10 --args 1 "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green'"
sleep 1
key Return
sleep 0.5
key F12
```

save script as 'xdt.txt', run it with xdotool

```
xdotool - < xdt.txt
```